# Alternative Flours Tortillas

Tags: substitutions

Trying to duplicate mom's fluffy soft all purpose flour tortillas but I want to use Chickpea + oat flour mix. I can't find a recipe with this combination which uses the same ingredients and methods as regular flour tortillas, and my efforts haven't produced the desired affect. Any solutions?

Comment: You might be able to get away with something like a corn tortilla with that blend, but not a wheat tortilla

Comment: Are you wedded to that mix of flours, or are you just looking for gluten-free?

Comment: What @Sneftel said.  There are other GF flours that would work better, such as rice and corn flour.

Answer (score 4):

This is because your plan is contradictory - the flours you have chosen are not suitable to producing a fluffy tortilla.

The largest problem is that your flours don't contain gluten. Without gluten, you can't get a fluffy dough that holds the miniature air bubbles contained in wheat flour doughs. The second problem is the chickpea flour - it is a rather chunky flour, which stays hard-ish even after full hydration.

The closest solution you will get is to start with oat flour only, without chickpea, and add vital wheat gluten to about the same percentage as found in all-purpose flour (8-9% of total weight, if your gluten is pure). Then do a couple of batches to test and fine-tune the recipe.

Once you have oat-with-gluten tortillas working, you can start doing new batches, gradually adding some chickpea flour. Make sure to leave the dough rest for a several hours, to hydrate the chickpea properly - or maybe even ditch the flour and use cooked, ground chickpeas, just like you'd prepare for hummus. You will soon find the proportion at which the chickpeas can be added without ruining the texture.

Comment: I suspect the OP is going for GF, and assumed a flour mix that worked for them in baked goods.

Comment: Thanks for responses. Sneftel, I'll use oat flour only. Would adding tapioca flour produce fluffy & soft tortillas? I will add a bit of all purpose flour to oat flour for now. Thx a bunch

Comment: @MariaWinter what makes them fluffy is the right ratio of gluten to starch. It doesn't matter that much if your starch comes from oats or from tapioca - if anything, the oat flour might be slightly better, because tapioca tends to be quite a waxy starch. You can indeed try making them with a combination of oat and all-purpose flour, I would start at 1:1 ratio, and continue adjusting from there.

Comment: Rumtscho, Great insight! thanks a mill for your input. I will do as you suggested .